# .NET Framework dependency in a .NET Core application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

[image]

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC web application. Some packages in NuGet have a dependency on the .NET Framework.

I am a bit confused about dependency on .NET Framework in a .NET Core application, because .NET Core is cross-platform.

What does it mean? Does it mean the .NET Framework should be installed?

Comment: You're reading the dependencies as an AND, you should be reading them as an OR.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're completely misinterpreting this information.

It just means:

***IF*** your code using `Moq` is running on .NET Framework >= v4.5

**THEN** `Moq` would have dependencies on the two other package listed.

But since you're using .NET Core, the dependencies in the ".NETStandard >= 2.0" section apply to your project.

Comment: does it mean that moq is coded in both .NetFramework and .Net Core enviroment so that could support both .NetFramework and .Net Core?

Comment: @HamidNoahdi: yes, exactly. The NUget package is available for **both** the full .NET Framework (v4.5 and newer), and **also** for any .NET platform that supports .NET Standard (>= 2.0) - which includes all .NET Core versions >= 2.0